# SOAP Request Composed of two XSD schema's

Tags: spring-boot, soap, maven-3, spring-ws, xjc

I've created a Spring SOAP Controller that is successfully getting my request in SOAPUI. Unfortunately while the main Request object is binding, along with an attribute the rest of the Request object is not.

The Request object itself is defined in an XSD and then the various fields within the Request object are defined by another XSD. I'm guessing it's either some Spring config or some kind of namespace issue with the Java object's generated by the XSD's. But I'm out of things to try and it's been two days.

Request XSD resulting Java object (POM XJC Creation):

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Request", propOrder = {
"customerInfo"
})
public class Request {

@XmlElement()
protected CustomerInfoType customerInfo;
@XmlAttribute(name = "schemaVersion")
protected String schemaVersion;
}
```

I can put whatever I want into schemaVersion and when I debug in the controller I see whatever I put in for it in SOAPUI.

CustomerInfoType XSD resulting Java object (POM XJC Creation):

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "CustomerInfoType", propOrder = {
"accountNumber",

})

public class CustomerInfoType {

protected BigInteger accountNumber;
}
```

Request is in a Request.xsd and CustomerInfoType is a CommonTypes.xsd

Here's the relative Spring Config:

```
@Bean(name = "RequestyDefinition")
public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchemaCollection requestSchemaCollection) {
    DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
    wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("RequestPort");
    wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
    wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://services.com/");
    wsdl11Definition.setSchemaCollection(requestSchemaCollection);
    return wsdl11Definition;
}

@Bean
public XsdSchemaCollection requestSchemaCollection(XsdSchema request, XsdSchema commonTypes) {
    return new XsdSchemaCollection() {

        public XsdSchema[] getXsdSchemas() {
            return new XsdSchema[]{request, commonTypes};
        }

        public XmlValidator createValidator() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    };
}

@Bean(name = "request")
public XsdSchema requestSchema()
{
    return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("Request.xsd"));
}

@Bean(name = "commonTypes")
public XsdSchema commonTypesSchema()
{
    return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("CommonTypes.xsd"));
}
```

I get a Request with null for CustomerInfoType but a value for the Request attribute....

Answer (score 0):

So my @PayloadRoot namespace was wrong because I'm generally confused by SOAP.

```
wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://services.com/");
```

Is correct but my namespace in the controller was also that and it needed to be the namespace of the XSD:
    services.types.com

as it was defined in the namespace of the SOAP request in SOAPUI.